# Parsing String with spaces to Date, lead to ParseException

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have date strings in this form `Thu Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2012`

I have tried to use this method to parse these String in a Date object

```
public Date fromStringToDate(String data) {
        Date result;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            result = sdf.parse(data);
            return result;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But doesn't works and I get this error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2012"
```

I suppose that the problem is caused by a wrong `SimpleDateFormat`, but I don't know the right syntax to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust the date format to the given string:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy
```

Make sure use the correct placeholders, case sensitive, etc. Take a look to the [Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Sorry, I had a mistake with the 'z' pattern, 'Z' is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Take a look to `Locale.US`, it is important to apply because the months and and days are in english.

Comment: doesn't work... same error... maybe the number of the `z` isn't correct :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this date formatting:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
```

Comment: doesn't work... same error... maybe the number of the z isn't correct :(